# Stiefväterlich behandeln?

Tags: etymology, word-choice, phrase, usage

Ein Kind, das man aufzieht, ohne daß es das eigene wäre, heißt Stiefsohn/Stieftochter. Der Elternteil heißt Stiefvater/Stiefmutter.

Wenn ein Mensch für etwas weniger Aufmerksamkeit aufbringt als für andere Dinge, dann behandelt dieser Mensch diese Sache "stiefmütterlich".

Gilt das nur, wenn dieser Mensch eine Frau ist und würde man bei Männern stattdessen "stiefväterlich" sagen? Und falls nicht, warum nicht?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***"Stiefväterlich"*** ist ein gutes Beispiel dafür, dass nicht alle Wörter, die in der deutschen Sprache verwendet werden, auch Einzug in den Duden erhalten, [dort](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/stiefv%C3%A4terlich) ist dieses Wort nämlich nicht aufgeführt.

Dennoch finden sich *"stiefväterlich"* und *"stiefväterlich behandelt"* im deutschen Schrifttum, wie man leicht anhand einer [Google Ngram Suche](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stiefm%C3%BCtterlich,stiefv%C3%A4terlich,stiefm%C3%BCtterlich%20behandelt,stiefv%C3%A4terlich%20behandelt&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3) sehen kann:

[image]

Auch im [Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GS46816#XGS46816) wird *"stiefväterlich"* belegt:

> STIEFVÄTERLICH, adj. , von stiefvater; seit dem 15. jh. bezeugt: stieffvaderlich vitricus Diefenbach 624a; styffveuterlich vitriceus ebda;

Die Verwendung von *"stiefväterlich"* ist seit dem 19. Jahrhundert stark rückläufig; dennoch findet man es auch in neueren Quellen:

> Wer heute »Stiefvater« wird – wir haben immer noch kein besseres Wort –, muss sich alle Mühe geben, gegen den (Selbst-)Verdacht anzuarbeiten, er behandele eines seiner Kinder stiefväterlich.<sup>[Die Zeit 20.01.2005 Nr.4](http://www.zeit.de/2005/04/V_8ater_2fLau_04)</sup>
>
> Die Deutsche Richterzeitung hat jetzt die Ergebnisse der ersten juristischen Staatsprüfung von 1982 veröffentlicht Sie belegen, daß Jungjuristen vom Staat stiefväterlich behandelt werden - übrigens hat dies und haben die schlechten Examensergebnisse Tradition.<sup>[Die Zeit 18.11.1983 Nr. 47](http://www.zeit.de/1983/47/zum-kriechen-gebracht)</sup>

Answer (score 10):

"Stiefväterlich" wird nicht verwendet und "stiefmütterlich" wird unabhängig vom Geschlecht verwendet.

Der Grund ist vermutlich, dass die vernachlässigte Sache, von der die Wendung kommt, ursprünglich die (Stief-)kinder waren. Und damals war es eben Aufgabe der (Stief-)mutter, sich um diese zu kümmern.

Answer (score 6):

Eine Google-Suche nach "stiefväterlich" bringt etwa 3500 Ergebnisse, bei "stiefmütterlich" kommen 325.000 Treffer, also fast das Hundertfache.

Aus dem Bauch heraus würde ich annehmen, dass die meisten Leser "stiefväterlich" verstehen würden, aber selbst nutzen würden die meisten wohl "stiefmütterlich".

Answer (score 4):

*Stiefväterlich* würde man, wenn überhaupt, in seiner wörtlichen Bedeutung als "vom Stiefvater herkommend" verwenden, z.B.

> Er verschleuderte sein stiefväterliches Erbe innerhalb von ein paar Monaten

- hier wäre *stiefmütterlich* natürlich sinnentstellend. Diese Verwendung dürfte sich auch hinter vielen der ngrams-Fundstellen verbergen.

Eine "stiefväterliche Behandlung" dürfte von den meisten verstanden werden, ist aber sehr unüblich.

Fragen nach dem Warum dürften unmöglich zu beantworten sein. Ich nehme an, aus demselben Grund warum das *Stiefmütterchen* (die Blume) kein *Stiefväterchen* an die Seite gestellt bekam.

Comment: Die Frage dürfte im Gegenteil leicht zu beantworten sein. Früher galt die Betreuung der Kinder als primäre Aufgabe der Mutter. Zwar wandelt sich die gesellschaftliche Praxis und auch das Bild von Vater- und Mutterrolle, aber für Metaphern greift man natürlich zu dominanten Bildern, nicht zu Ausnahmen.

Comment: @userunknown Früher hatten die Männer die Oberaufsicht über die Finanzen. Eine "finanziell stiefmütterliche" Behandlung wäre also stiefväterlich. Das greift nicht.

Comment: Ich habe eine Antwort hinzugefügt, die diese Frage behandelt.

Comment: Hast Du Belege für Deine Behauptung? Bei den im [DWDS gelistiteten Referenzen](https://www.dwds.de/r?corpus=public;q=stiefv%C3%A4terlich) finden sich jedenfalls mehr Erwähnungen mit der von Dir verneinten übertragenen Bedeutung, als solche mit der wörtlichen, Deshalb auch meine damalige Antwort, das hat sich in den letzten sieben Jahren nämlich nicht geändert.

Comment: @Takkat Ich habe mir stichprobenartig deine ngrams-Suchergebnisse einverleibt. Ist das Beleg genug?

Comment: @tofro: leider nein, denn es gibt die übertragene Bedeutung durchaus (und nur das wurde gefragt):https://www.google.de/search?q=%22stiefv%C3%A4terlich%22 - du müsstest hier mit den Ergebnissen Deiner Stichproben etwas anderes belegen. Selbst im Grimm wird schon die **häufigere** übertragene Bedeutung erwähnt.

Comment: Dass man "stiefmütterlich" im Zusammenhang mit finanzieller Ausstattung (Behandlung?) benutzt hat, war aber nicht meine Behauptung. Man könnte in solchen Fällen zu einer ganz anderen Metapher gegriffen haben oder zu gar keiner Metapher. Es gibt in der Sprache auch nicht das Bild vom Rabenvater.

Answer (score 3):

Standardsprachlich würde ich immer *stiefmütterlich* sagen, unabhängig vom Geschlecht. Die deutsche Sprache ist aber sehr flexibel, so dass *stiefväterlich* wohl von vielen sofort verstanden wird, wenn auch erst nach einem kurzen Moment der Überraschung. Der Duden verzeichnet das Wort nicht, [bietet aber *stiefmütterlich* als Alternative an](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/stiefv%C3%A4terlich).